# What’s the reading order for the Ultimate ‘Death of Spider-Man’ storyline?

Tags: suggested-order, spider-man, marvel

I want to catch up with the story of [Ultimate Spider-Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Comics%3a_Spider-Man). What is the recommended reading order surrounding the *Death of Spider-Man* storyline?

I know there are about 30 issues about Miles Morales, but with *Death of Spider-Man* starting at #153-#160, would I also have to read the *Ultimate Avengers vs. New Ultimates* #1-#6 and *Ultimate Fallout* #1-#6 in order to understand the story leading up to the Miles Morales story? Or could I just read *Death of Spider-Man* #153-#160?

Answer (score 3):

A copy of the order from the link provided by sumbuddyx.

For Backup and more importantly so you don't have to click the link.

Ultimate Avengers vs. New Ultimates #1 - Part One of Six

Ultimate Spider-Man #153 - Death of Spider-Man: Prelude

Ultimate Spider-Man #154 - Death of Spider-Man: Prelude

Ultimate Spider-Man #155 - Death of Spider-Man: Prologue

Ultimate Spider-Man #156 - Death of Spider-Man, Chapter 1

Ultimate Avengers vs. New Ultimates #2 - Part Two

Ultimate Spider-Man #157 - Death of Spider-Man, Chapter Two

Ultimate Avengers vs. New Ultimates #3 - Part Three

Ultimate Spider-Man #158 - Death of Spider-Man, Part Three of Five

Ultimate Avengers vs. New Ultimates #4 - Part 4

Ultimate Fallout #1 - Chapter One of Six

Ultimate Fallout #2 - Chapter Two of Six

Ultimate Fallout #3 - Chapter Three of Six

Ultimate Spider-Man #159 - Death of Spider-Man: Part 4 of 5

Ultimate Avengers vs. New Ultimates #5 - Part 5

Ultimate Avengers vs. New Ultimates #6 - Part Six

Ultimate Fallout #4 - Chapter Four of Six

Ultimate Fallout #5 - Chapter Five of Six

Ultimate Fallout #6 - Chapter Six of Six

Ultimate Spider-Man #160 - Death of Spider-Man: Part 5 of 5

Comment: sweet. i started typing this out once and then for some reason gave up and then forgot about it til now. i hope the dude comes back and says if it was helpful or something, did he read it or anything.

Comment: If you want to tag it onto your answer I'll delete mine.

Comment: no it's cool, i don't mind and i upvoted you too. i just wondered if the dude ever come back and checked out our answers.

Answer (score 0):

For the full reading order (if you were to all read the books that tie-in) follow this link http://www.comicvine.com/death-of-spider-man/4045-56343/

I didn't read any of the tie-ins to Death of Spider-man and I understood the story perfectly. The tie-ins function as what you might call a sidequel: it's happening at the same time as DOSM and crosses over very, very briefly, but they have their own story going on. It gives more colour to the world.

As to Ultimate Fallout, I'd read that if you were at the point you'd already read DOSM. It follows on from it and explores how people are responding to what happened in DOSM. Miles' role in it is very minimal (he only appears in half of issue #4) but it is a very cool introduction.

Comment: It would be great if you could edit in the suggested order, just in case something happens to the link.

Comment: sorry for the delay guys i ahve so much going on in life as i know we all do but yes i have read all those books and yes this was a big help, i wanna say thank you for the info u added and it made reading these books all the better,when i first started this i was a REAL rookie i like to thing im better now lol thanks again